# How to order shapes on a canvas - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I want to make a shape (an XP bar) to always be ordered at the top of all shapes drawn.

How would this be possible, (I also use *p5.js* too, if that helps.) other than drawing it last (which I cannot do in my situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two main options:

**Option one:** Draw it last. This is the easiest way to do it. If you "cannot" do it this way for some reason, that sounds like you need to refactor your code then.

**Option two:** Use 3D coordinates to draw it with a Z coordinate that's closer to the user. Most drawing functions can take 3D coordinates instead of 2D coordinates. This should work, but it's more complicated than just drawing it last.

Comment: Let's talk about drawing it last, I can't use the 3d option as it is too intensive. I should have talked about why I could not have done it. I am translating the map around the player, but I want to draw shapes on top of it like a GUI. However, just adding it at the end means, the GUI will move with the map. Any ideas to how I could work around that?

Comment: @Canatron First off, you should get into the habit of trying things before you say you can't do them. How do you know the 3d option is too intensive? Did you actually try it? As for drawing the xp bar on top of the map, you just have to draw it where you want it. I don't know how you're drawing your map, so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Ouch... Truth hurts... but in all seriousness... I did try displacing my map in the opposite direction and it worked, so thank you for all your help, and I will make sure to be more open minded to suggestions and try what is suggested. Respect.